# How to receive the data that is being passed from client app to the jsreport server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, post, jsreport

I am trying to generate a pdf report from my angular app connecting to jsreport.  My client app is doing a POST call by passing a sample data to the report server in this way.

```
 $http.post('http://localhost:5488/api/report', {
      'template': {
        'shortid': 'SypJSv75e',
        "data": {"name": "John Doe"}
      }
    })
    .success(function (response) {
     console.log(response)
    });
```

As you see in the above code that I am passing {"name": "John Doe"} to the report server.

On the report server, this is the code that I have in the custom scripts section.

```
function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
req.data.generatedOn = new Date();
done();
}
```

How do I receive the data in the jsreport that is being passed from client app?

Comment: Did you fix this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` property should not be inside the `template` and your request should look like this

```js
$http.post('http://localhost:5488/api/report', {
      template: { shortid: 'SypJSv75e' },
      data: { name: "John Doe"}
    })
    .success(function (response) {
     console.log(response)
    });
```

Then you can reach "John Doe" inside template content using `{{name}}` or in custom script as

```js
function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
  //prints into debug John Doe
  console.log(req.data.name)
  done();
}
```

You can later consider using [jsreport browser javascript client](https://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client) to invoke rendering calls.

Comment: Supposed that the passed data is JSON.stringify of an object array, e.g: 0: 'title', 1: [ { content: 'content', content2: 'content2'} ] can I call and pass it the same way? Like: `"data": { "data": data },` I would pass it by `var datapassed = req.data.data` in `beforeRender` function, then I can access datapassed[0], and datapassed[1] for 'string' and json contents right? As far as I can try when I used debug it was passed successfully. By then how can I replace the existing sample-data used in xlsx template? I tried using the {{{title}}} it wasn't able to be called.

Comment: I also tried using `Object.assign(req.data, datapassed);` but it wasn't passed to the template sample data.